# HTTPs is not working in Service Fabric with Docker Container

Tags: docker, ssl, https, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I am developing a Self-hosted .Net Core Rest API to be hosted in Docker Container in Service Fabric. I am unable to configure to SSL/Https in Service Fabric. Http seems to work. I am using HttpSys as web server, not Kestrel since I read it is not recommended option for services without reverse proxy(like IIS).

Here is the web server code snippet.

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseHttpSys(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.Authentication.Schemes = AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    }
                )                  
                .Build();
```

Here is ServiceManifest.xml Endpoints snippet.

```
<Endpoints>      
  <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="80" />
  <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpointHttps" Protocol="https" Port="443" Type="Input" CertificateRef="SSLCertificate" />
</Endpoints>
```

Here is ApplicationManifest EnvironmentVariable snippet.

```
<EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_URLS" Value="https://*:443/;http://*:80/"/>
```

Here is ApplicationManifest.xml Policies snippet.

```
<Policies>
  <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
    <RepositoryCredentials AccountName="accountname" Password="password" PasswordEncrypted="false" />
    <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint"/>
    <PortBinding ContainerPort="443" EndpointRef="ServiceEndpointHttps"/> 
  </ContainerHostPolicies>
  <EndpointBindingPolicy CertificateRef="SSLCertificate" EndpointRef="ServiceEndpointHttps" />
</Policies>
```

Here is ApplicationManifest.xml Certificates snippet.

```
<Certificates>
<EndpointCertificate Name="SSLCertificate" X509FindValue="cert thumbprint"/>
</Certificates>
```

Initially, I had issues with Certificate deployment when I had SSL certificate only in CurrentUser\My Certificate Store. I resolved it after deploying the certificate in LocalMachine\My Certificate Store. With this fix, Service seems to be working only with HTTP protocol in Port 80, not with HTTPS protocol in Port 443.

Service Fabric Explorer doesn't show any error and no errors in Events Log also. I am facing this issue in both Local Service Fabric and in Azure Service Fabric instances.

Any thoughts/pointers on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What base os are you using for the service fabric, Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Service fabric uses Windows OS.

Comment: Check this out, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux), deploying a linux container to service fabric.

Comment: hi.. do u have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Service Fabric for container and https could follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-securing-containers).

It will inject the certificate into the container as environment variables.

But for linux clusters, there is a problem. The **Certificates_ServicePackageName_CodePackageName_CertName_PEM** and **Certificates_ServicePackageName_CodePackageName_CertName_PrivateKey** represented files are having the exact same content.

I'm waiting for the Azure China supporter for further clarification on this, not sure if it's a China specific problem.